# Добавление класса к активной ссылке

Tags: jquery

Пробивал с помощью `.hasClass()`, но как оказалось работать не будет:

`.hasClass('active')` - если содержит класс, то функция вернет `true`, иначе вернет false.
`.toggleClass('active', )` - `true` — в случае добавления класса, `false` — иначе.

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).hasClass('active'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Вопрос: как максимально коротко сделать добавление класса к ссылке, на которую нажал и потом удаление с ее класса если нажал на другую ссылку?

Comment: Не претендует на лучший, но вот: https://jsfiddle.net/n0rqjf2r/ . Так может даже прозрачней :D: https://jsfiddle.net/on07g6wf/ .

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, максимально ли коротко получилось, но рабочий вариант:

```js
$("div").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("div a").removeClass("active");
  $(e.target).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
a,
a:active,
a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.active {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#1">test 1</a>
  <a href="#2">test 2</a>
  <a href="#3">test 3</a>
  <a href="#4">test 4</a>
  <a href="#5">test 5</a>
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/x4b99wbb/)